# Printing links from a text file produces "line gap" in between

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, text, readlines

When I print links stored in a `text` file, the result I'm getting constantly kinda weird which is in this case a line gap between each link. If i use `.strip()` then it fixes the problem but it doesn't seem satisfactory usage. My question is: how can i get usual results other than using `.strip()`? Thanks in advance.

This is what I tried:

```
with open('reverse.txt', 'r') as file:
    for item in file.readlines():
        print(item)
        print(item.strip()) # ain't there any better way? It fixes, though.
```

The results:

```
http://metaladhesive.tradeindia.com/

http://www.iari.res.in/

http://www.peekayfarmequipments.com/
```

What I'm expecting:

```
http://metaladhesive.tradeindia.com/
http://www.iari.res.in/
http://www.peekayfarmequipments.com/
```

Btw, the same thing applicable for `csv` files as well.

Comment: `print(item,end='')`

Comment: Your line already have an endline character, print will also add one. setting `end=''` as @MichaelO.'s  answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readlines()` retains the line break. You *could* instead use `file.read().splitlines()`, where `read()` returns the whole file as a string (with newlines), and `splitlines()` is a method of `str` which removes them.

However, I think you should keep your code as it is. Just strip the line after you read it.